# Analyzing encrypted Android apps (.asec)?

Tags: android, encryption

I've been trying to reverse engineer a paid android app that writes out some binary data so that I can export that data into other programs (it's a run/walk timer app, if anyone's curious, and I'm trying to get its GPS traces out). However, it looks like the apk is encrypted and stored in `/data/app-asec/[app_id].asec`.

There's a nice [blog post](http://nelenkov.blogspot.com/2012/07/using-app-encryption-in-jelly-bean.html) that says the encryption used is TwoFish, with a key stored in `/data/misc/systemkeys/AppsOnSD.sks`, but I haven't been able to decrypt the file using the naïve strategy of just using that key directly with TwoFish on the `.asec`.

How can I decrypt this to get an apk I can actually analyze?

Note: I realize that this information is considered somewhat delicate in places like xda-developers, since it could be used to enable piracy. I have no such intentions, I just want to examine the serialization code.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After a little bit more work and some more careful re-reading, I figured out my mistake: the files in `/data/app-asec/` are the encrypted *containers*. They're actually dm-crypt volumes, which then get mounted at `/mnt/asec/[app_id]`. The `pkg.apk` in that directory is the unencrypted apk that can be analyzed using any of the fine tools in [this answer](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/46/257).